# Two of my variables cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, int, conways-game-of-life

```
public static void nextGeneration(boolean[][] currentWorld, boolean[][] newWorld) {

    boolean[][] world = null;
    world = currentWorld;
    int numLivingNeighbors = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentWorld.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < currentWorld[i].length; j++)
            numLivingNeighbors =numNeighborsAlive(world, i, j);
            boolean cellCurrentlyLiving = world[i][j];
            isCellLivingInNextGeneration(numLivingNeighbors,currentWorld[i[j]);
```

I am getting an error that says i and j can't be resolved to a variable. 
I tried declaring them, but then I got an error that stated they had been declared twice.

Comment: There should be a closing square bracket after the i on the last line. - currentWorld[i][j]

Comment: More importantly, you want an open brace at the end of the nested loop declaration - ask your IDE to format your code and you'll see what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets in your `for` loops:

```
public static void nextGeneration(boolean[][] currentWorld, boolean[][] newWorld) {
    boolean[][] world = null;
    world = currentWorld;
    int numLivingNeighbors = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentWorld.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < currentWorld[i].length; j++) {
            numLivingNeighbors =numNeighborsAlive(world, i, j);
            boolean cellCurrentlyLiving = world[i][j];
            isCellLivingInNextGeneration(numLivingNeighbors,currentWorld[i[j]);
        }
    }

    // might there be other code you did not show us?

    return;
}
```

When you use a `for` loop *without* brackets, then it will only consider the immediate line or following line as being part of the loop.  So your original code was effectively the same as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentWorld.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < currentWorld[i].length; j++) {
        numLivingNeighbors =numNeighborsAlive(world, i, j);
    }
}
boolean cellCurrentlyLiving = world[i][j];
isCellLivingInNextGeneration(numLivingNeighbors,currentWorld[i[j]);
```

In other words, you were referencing the `loop` variables `i` and `j` *outside* of the actual loop.